# autossh not behaving as expected

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

I am trying to use autossh, like so:

```
autossh -f -i id_rsa -D 8080 user@myserver.com
```

However, on both an PPC Tiger eMac and a Mountain Lion MacBook Pro, I just get presented with the argument and environment variable list.

Both machines have autossh 1.4c installed. I am focused on getting it working on the Tiger machine; I only tried it on my Mountain Lion MBP to see if the issue was Tiger-specific.

Comment: With option `-D` `ssh` will act as a SOCKS server, is this your intent? If you try `ssh -i id_rsa -D 8080 user@myserver.com`, does it work as expected? If it does, if you drop option `-f` in `autossh`, does it work? If it doesn't, you will have to troubleshoot first why `ssh` fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this before and the issue for me was autossh expects a specified monitoring port (even though this is optional according to the usage `stdout`).

```
autossh -M 12345 -f -i id_rsa -D 8080 user@myserver.com
```

This similar command works for me against autossh 1.4c installed via homebrew on mountain lion.